# Twitter search api always return 15 tweets

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter

When I call the twitter search API, to search on tweets with a certain hashtag, it always returns 15 tweets, even though I set the count to five.

```
  $.ajax({
        url:'http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
            type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            q: %23twitter,
            count: 5    
        }, 
          success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                         //some code
        }
```

Does anyone knows what could be the problem?

EDIT: Other parameters like include_entities are not working either.

Comment: According to this documentation : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search there is no `count` parameter. Have you tried setting `page` to `1` and `rpp` to `5` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct! I was looking at the 1.1 documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
data: {
    q: %23twitter,
    page : 1,
    rpp :  4
},
```

if you only want to get X number of tweets, set rpp to X-1